# How can you create a Firestore compound query that returns all documents in an array of mapped objects?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I want to avoid returning documents from Firestore that I do not need. I have a collection of documents with the following properties:

```
membership {array}
  0 {map}
    contactGroupId: "1da9a73f89f8ca4c"
    contactGroupResourceName: "contactGroup/1da9a73f89f8ca4c"
  1 {map}
    contactGroupId: "1da9a73f89f8ca4c"
    contactGroupResourceName: "contactGroup/1da9a73f89f8ca4c"
```

I want to create a compound query that only returns documents if the **contactGroupId** is equal to **1da9a73f89f8ca4c**. Something like `ref.where(membership.{key}.contactGroupId, "==", "1da9a73f89f8ca4c")`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to filter documents using the contents of a map field inside an array.  You will need to restructure your data if you want to perform this query.  You have two options.

1. Put all of the `contactGroupId` values into their own array field, and use an [array-contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) query to find them.
2. Instead of using an array, use the `contactGroupId` value as the name of a map key that you can use in a query, like `where(`membership.1da9a73f89f8ca4c.present`, '==', true)`.  Your membership field would be structure like this:

```
membership (map)
  - 1da9a73f89f8ca4c
    - present (boolean)
    - contactGroupResourceName = "contactGroup/1da9a73f89f8ca4c"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was afraid this might be the answer. The data is imported from the Google People API and I kept the structure returned by the API.